# Firebase Remote Config - copy to another project

Tags: firebase, flutter, config, firebase-remote-config

I have two projects for dev and prod. I want to be able to run a script to copy dev config to prod.

Firebase Remote Config has an API for programatically updating Remote Config. But as far as I can tell, you need to init `admin` with a project-specific service account. It seems like I would need two admin instances, but I'm not sure that's possible?

I'm wondering if someone has done this before and has an example script. Thanks!

See docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc

Answer (score 1):

There is no Firebase Admin SDK for Flutter, so you'll have to implement this on a different platform that **is** supported. For a list of these platforms and instructions on setting it up, see the documentation on [adding Firebase to a server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

For these platforms that the Firebase Admin SDK targets, you *can* create multiple instances of the `FirebaseApp` class, and initialize each of them with different credentials and project configuration. For examples of how to do this, see the documentation on [initializing multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps).